# How can I force mesh to remesh along a polyline?

Tags: mesh, snapping, bmesh

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am coming from a scientific field and have begun to use blender more and more, and it is just amazingly powerful. But, sometimes I find that to do precision type work and have precise control over meshing is a bit hard because the workflow is not really set up for that (I think?).

Basically, I have a mesh. I want to draw a polyline on this mesh, but not where any edges/vertices are currently occupying. Then I want to remesh the mesh and have edges/vertices snap to this polyline.

Is this possible in Blender?

See below schematic of what I'm attempting to do.

I have my target mesh that I'm trying to remesh, and I created a Curve>Path object t use as my snapping line.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: current]

[image: goal]

Comment: I was able to find an approach by converting the curve to a mesh, shrink wrapping it to the target mesh, then deleting the faces of the target mesh in and around the curve, then joining both meshes to a single mesh and filling in the faces again...but there has to be a better way

Comment: It seems to me [Kinfe Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) might be useful to you in this situation. (It cuts along the angle of the camera; so what you see is what you get,) You can convert your curve object (I assume the poly line is one) to a mesh by selecting it and using ALT + C and choose Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text.

Comment: By the way, the cutting object can be a mesh or curve. No need to covert it. My mistake.

Comment: this was definitely helpful and did achieve more or less what I was after .. I still need to explore how I could have more control over the spacing and remeshing around this perimeter. If you want to add as an answer I will accept @Fjoersteller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to you comments:

Apart from the Knife Project and using a Shrinkwrap Modifier, the only thing i can think of, is using a Shrinkwrap Modifier with a specific Vertex Group. You would have to manually select the vertices around the edge of the polyline mesh object.

[image]

[image]

If the vertices need to stay on the same height you could also extrude the polyline mesh object and have the Shrinkwrap Mode: set to surface.

For the "more control over the spacing and remeshing" (if you were to delete any unwanted faces) the commands [Grid Fill](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html) and [Triangulate Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/triangulate_faces.html) might come in handy. And possibly [Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/randomize.html) to make it look more organic afterwards.

That's all i got. Hope it helps. In any case, good luck. : )

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks